# Unit Testing IdentityContext

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, asp.net-identity

I've recently rewritten an MVC 4 app as MVC 5, so that I can use ASP.NET identity. My old tests were set up as follows (I have no connection string in the test project)

context:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext {
public MyDbContext() : base("name=DefaultContext") {}...
```

test:

```
var mockVoteSet = new Mock<DbSet<Vote>>();

var mockContext = new Mock<MyDbContext> { CallBase = true };
mockContext.Setup(c => c.Votes).Returns(mockVoteSet.Object);        

var service = new VoteService(mockContext.Object);

var result = service.Vote(1, "1", false);    
//then assert result
```

This was working well, and all my tests were passing.

Since moving over my context now inherits from IdentityDbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext: IdentityDbContext<User> {       
        public MyDbContext() : base("name=DefaultContext") { } ...
```

I now get an error when passing a mock of the context to the service in the test:

> No connection string named 'DefaultContext' could be found in the
>   application config file.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Already tried something like this?

```
Public interface IMyDbContext
{
    DbSet Votes { get; set;}
    void SaveChanges();
}

Public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User> , IMyDbContext
{
    Public DbSet Votes { get; set;}
    Public void SaveChanges(){
      //...
    }

}

var mockVoteSet = new Mock<DbSet<Vote>>(){ CallBase = true };
var _context = new Mock<IMyDbContext>(MockBehavior.Strict);
_context.Setup(c => c.Votes).Returns(mockVoteSet.Object); 

var service = new VoteService(_context.Object);
```

Comment: thanks! its just missing the implementation of SaveChanges() in MyDbContext